# Keep checking if page has scroll bars and re-run function each time if there are?

Tags: jquery

The following code checks if the page has scroll bars. If not then it finds the first 3 divs with a class of "result" and "hidden" and removes the "hidden" class:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    if ($(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden');
    }

});
```

This is working fine however I need the code to keep checking if there are not scroll bars, and if not remove the "hidden" class from the next 3 elements with a class of "result". This should stop when there are no more elements with the class, or enough have been shown that scroll bars are now in the browser.

Ive tried to use the while and do commands however this shows all the divs. I think this is because the while condition is only checked once, not after more elements are shown. How can I recheck the condition each time?

```
$(window).load(function() {

    do {
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden').find('img').each(showImg);
    }
    while ($(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `while`, you risk to fall in an infinite loop. The `while` loop is executed forever, as long as the condition is true, and as fast as the computer can handle it. In other words, it freezes your code and your browser until the condition is false and the loop is broken.

Instead of a continuous `while` instruction, check your condition every 50 or 100ms using `setInterval` :

```
setInterval( function(){
    if ($(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
        $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden');
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want listen for the window resize event, I would do something like this...

```
    function checkForScrollBars () {
      if ($(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { 
          $(".result.hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('hidden');
      }
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        checkForScrollBars();
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
        checkForScrollBars();
    });
```